# How to analyze Kentico 7 installation for dependencies and custom web parts

Tags: analysis, kentico

Using Kentico for the first time and have inherited a version 7 project with custom web parts. There are folders with .cs files, folders with .dlls, and folders with .ascx/ascx.cs web parts. Most are active. Some are not.

What's the best way to assess what is used and what is compiled when looking at a Kentico instance? I'm trying to sort what Kentico stores for configuration, how Kentico knows what to compile, and how Kentico provides a pathway for custom ascx/ascx.cs webparts to use (via `using`) various libraries in folders on the Kentico instance folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

Having worked with Kentico for quite a while it's pretty easy to identify them simply by looking in a few directories.

If you haven't worked with it before you might try to do a fresh install of version 7 which you can get from the [Kentico Client Portal](https://client.kentico.com) and compare them.

If the install was done with best practices, you can [look in the following documentation](https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/devguide/index.html?folder_structure_and_importexport.htm) and the "custom code" should be in the green and blue directories in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open-sourced utility called [KInspector](https://github.com/Kentico/KInspector) (it`s made by Kentico consulting team). This utility should show you your custom code (among the others) in Kentico instance (afaik it is in the Analysis module).